# Why is Ubuntu asking me for a password? (I didn't set one.)

Tags: wireless, password

I'm from Mexico City, living in the US now. I recently put Ubuntu in my PC and tried to set the wireless connection but i need a five digit password I never set. Do you now how to change this? Thanks so much and I really like Ubuntu, having used it on my computer in Mexico.

Comment: Check underneath the router?

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless connection is protected. You need to provide the password which is required to authenticate your modem.

Answer (score 1):

If the password is for the wireless connection then you will have to speak with the person who sold you the router or check the documentation that it came with for mention of a default password.